# How to tell users how much memory your iOS application needs

Tags: ios, memory, alert

I'm developing an iOS application which (like any other) requires a certain amount of free memory to run correctly. In my case - at least 4MB, I cannot use any less than that. It's a fairly small amount, but a few times (on my device at least) I got only 2MB free and the program crashed. What do you think is the best way to tell users how much memory you need. I know the code to get the currently available memory, but even if I tell the user (like in a UIAlertView when the user starts the program) that he is running low, what can I suggest him to do to free more memory (except turning off and on the device). Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you getting these memory size numbers from, the Object Allocations instrument or the Memory Monitor one?  The latter will give you a more accurate reading of your application's total memory size (which is probably greater than 4 MB).

Comment: Hello, Brad :) I use Instrument's Object Allocations, haven't even heard of Memory Monitor :) I'll check for it and give it a try :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which kinds of iPhone devices your app is being tested? I suppose that the iOS has to do its job well to free enough memory for you or kill alll background app so it can have more memory

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response :) Well, I test it on iPod Touch 2G. I don't think the memory will be an issue for iPad or iPhone 4, but there maybe a trouble for iPhone 3G/3GS, which have less memory on them.

Comment: There should be no trouble with iPhone 3G/3GS, which has around 128-256MB of RAM and usually available at least half of them

Comment: That's true, but when the user starts and quits different programs, the iPhone does not always clear the entire memory they were using and the available free space reduces. iPod Touch 2G also has 128MB of ram, but a few times the free memory was just 2MB and even less.

Answer (score 1):

On older devices you can't really rely on getting more than 8MB.  4MB is a great target, and if through your profiling you've determined that's all you need, you should be fine.

However, I think the concept here is that if you receive memory warnings you wouldn't bother the user with those types of things.  I would find it pretty annoying myself.  It would be better to limit your app's activity or throttle back whatever you are doing that is so memory intensive.

Comment: I completely agree with this - I think presenting the user with a message regarding application implementation detail runs contrary to everything iOS is trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello, slf :) I know it's annoying, but I don't see any other option. The issue is that I'm developing an alarm clock, and it requires the 4MB when an alarm is fired. So, if at that time the user has not enough free memory, the application terminates, and the alarm sound is not played, hence the user is late for work :) So I need to inform him somehow of potential failure (I prefer that than getting bad reviews on the AppStore) :) Thank you :)

Comment: It takes 4MB to play an alarm sound?  Kids.  I remember when all we had was 4KB for our whole program, and we liked it.  :-)